# Waiting for a serial message before proceeding in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm currently working on an interface between C# and an arduino project. I'm using the serial port to send and receive messages from the arduino and so far everything looks fine.

However I came to a point, where I want to send a string to the arduino and wait for a response until I'm going to send over the next string.

I figured that I cannot simply timeout here since my RichTextField is also going to freeze and the "OK*" message cannot be read from there.

I've read about some other solutions online but since I'm very new to C# I hope that somebody can point me in the right direction.

Best regards

//Edited the post with a full code example:

```
            using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.IO;
        using System.IO.Ports;


        namespace interface_test
        {
            public partial class Form1 : Form
            {

                string serialDataIn;

                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    Enable_Console();

                    comboBox_baudRate.Text = "115200";
                    comboBox_comPort.Text = "COM3";
                    string[] portLists = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
                    comboBox_comPort.Items.AddRange(portLists);
                }

                        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }

                /* erase textbox contents */
                private void button_clearLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    richTextBox_receiveMsg.Text = "";
                }

                /* listening to the serial port */
                private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
                {
                    serialDataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
                }

                /* process the serial data */
                public void ShowData(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string trimmedMsg = serialDataIn;
                    richTextBox_receiveMsg.Text += trimmedMsg;

                    if (trimmedMsg.Contains("Initialization done."))
                    {
                        button_detectCEM.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }

                /* open COM-port to arduino */
                private void button_openCom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        serialPort1.PortName = comboBox_comPort.Text;
                        serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_baudRate.Text);
                        serialPort1.Open();
                        Enable_Console();

                        button_detectCEM.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                    }
                }

                /* close COM-port to arduino */
                private void button_closeCom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            serialPort1.Close();

                            Enable_Console();
                        }
                        catch (Exception error)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }

                
                private void button_fileBrowser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    openAndWrite();
                }

                public void openAndWrite()
                {
                    /* load a .txt file */
                        
                    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                    openFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT files (*.txt)|*.txt";
                    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
                    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
                    string selectedFile = "";

                    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        selectedFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    }

                    /* parse file and store it in data[] */
                    byte[] data;

                    using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(selectedFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        data = new byte[fsSource.Length];
                        int numBytesToRead = (int)fsSource.Length;
                        int numBytesRead = 0;
                        while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                        {
                            // Read may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                            int n = fsSource.Read(data, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                            // Break when the end of the file is reached.
                            if (n == 0)
                                break;

                            numBytesRead += n;
                            numBytesToRead -= n;
                        }
                        numBytesToRead = data.Length;
                    }

                for (int i = 0; i < BitConverter.ToInt32(blockLength, 0); i++)
                {
                    data[i] = data[offset + i];
                }

                    
                    /* write data block */
                        
                    offset = 0;

                    while (offset < data.Length)
                    {
                        byte[] dataString = new byte[6];
                        string blockMsg = "FFFFFF";

                        int start = offset;
                        offset += 6;

                        if (offset > data.Length) offset = data.Length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                        {
                            if ((start + i) < data.Length) dataString[i] = data[start + i];
                        }

                        blockMsg += BitConverter.ToString(dataString).Replace("-", string.Empty);
                        blockMsg += "*";


                        serialPort1.Write(blockMsg);
                            
                        //Wait for "OK*" before next Message...

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a WinForms client? It appears your using an event to receive the data.  This would seem to indicate there is more code involved here than you are showing.  Personally, I would probably receive data to a globally accessible variable and then use another thread to place it into the text box and optionally send something when OK* is received. You may need to get into threading a bit here to do what you want.

Comment: Yes this is a WinForms client, however I'm using a single class and the rest of the code doesnt play a role for what I want to do here so I cut it for readbility.

My global variable in that case would be serialDataIn. I've never done anything with threading. Can you maybe give me a keyword here I can look up?

Comment: If you want to use a loop like that and wait for a response from the Arduino, you could run that loop in a separate thread than the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways that you could solve this. My approach would be to make use of the [TaskCompletionSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=net-6.0) class and a lambda function. Here's a rough example, you'll need to make the method containing this code [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), and potentially have it return a Task to await it all the way up the chain.

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

serialPort1.DataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
   SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)s;
   string newData = sp.ReadExisting();
   tcs.SetResult(newData);
}

serialPort1.Write(Msg);
var dataFromPort = await tcs.Task;
```

I'm away from an IDE, nor do I have access to all your code, so without the wider context it's hard to know exactly what else you might need. But I've done some Arduino work in the past, and this is how I solved the problem.

EDIT :: Thinking about it, you might (test it first) run into a problem because that event isn't being unsubscribed from and the code is running in a loop. **IF** that turns out to be a problem, you could make use of C#'s [Local Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) to handle the event subscription, like this:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

void localHandler(object s, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.DataReceived -= localHandler;
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)s;
    string newData = sp.ReadExisting();
    tcs.SetResult(newData);
};

serialPort1.DataReceived += localHandler
serialPort1.Write(Msg);
var dataFromPort = await tcs.Task;
```

It might look a little strange, but it's certainly cleaner (IMO) then needing to keep track of instance variables and manually manage threads.

EDIT2 :: Tested when I was sat at a computer, if I understand your requirement correctly, this should do everything you need.

Comment: Mh, so I tried your code, made the method async but now I get a STA Problem with the File Dialog. apparently I need to put [STAThread] in front of the Main() Method, but I don't have a Main() or a Program.cs... I'm doing terrible here sorry again.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. You should just be able to change the signature of "button_fileBrowser_Click" to "private aync void", the signature of "openAndWrite" to "public Task" and then, within the "button_fileBrowser_Click", simply "await openAndWrite()";

Any other threading code shouldn't need to exist. Task and async/await are designed to abstract away that complexity for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this clarified it once more for me! I should be able to move on from here! Marked your answer as solution.

Comment: Most welcome. Thanks for marking as the solution.

Please do have a read of the async/await documentation I linked to, there's some stumbling blocks that can trip new people up - it's abstracting away a huge amount of complexity after all.

Comment: Maybe just as a follow up since the code is working now, I understand, that after I wrote the Msg, we are waiting for the dataFromPort. Is there a way to read that data in my current method and evaluate it? In case I still wan't to handle a message from arduino? ("OK*" / "NOT OK*") This is mainly to make the code a bit more flexible. I tried setting up a bool in the localHandler but that didnt work.

Comment: Declare a variable outside of the scope of the local handler, and then from within the local handler do whatever you need to do to set the variable. Most likely that'll be just reading X amount of bytes from the serial port and parsing the message.

At that point, just inspect the variable after the "await tcs.Task;" line and you should be able to do whatever you need.

Comment: I added a "byte[] buffer" in front of the local handler and inside the handler I`m try to read with serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length). However I`m not getting any data at all. I tried Read, ReadExisting, nothing gives me a value from my serial port.

Comment: Call the SerialPort.ReadExisting method instead. It returns a string and should contain everything you need. I've got my 2nd example updated to show how it should be done.

Comment: I set it up exactly according to your code. Also newData doesnt deliver.

Answer (score 0):

This may take you in the right direction.

It might be useful in this case to separate the data received from the display update thread.  Since the data received is an event, it will be coming in on its own thread, likely from some component - in this case the serial port.

The form, and all the display objects on it, run on a single thread, owned by the form.

You can use a timer as a background thread to make the leap between what was received and what you want to do/display.

For example, one way is to use a concurrent queue and a timer to poll the status of the queue.

```
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;

    private ConcurrentQueue<string> dataIn = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(CheckQue,null,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    private void CheckQue(object state)
    {
        while(dataIn.TryDequeue(out var data))
        {
            ShowData(data);

            if (data.Contains("OK*"))
            {
                //Do Something
                //Better yet raise an event that does something
               Msg += BitConverter.ToString(dataString).Replace("-", string.Empty);
               Msg += "*";

               serialPort1.Write(Msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then modify your above code to add to the queue when data is received

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataIn.Enqueue(SerialPort1.ReadExisting());
    }
```

And since your using a windows form, you need to make sure you don't get a cross-threaded operation when updating it, by marshaling the update onto the form's thread like so.

```
    public static void ShowData(string data)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var del = new MethodInvoker(() => ShowData(data));
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(del);
                return;
            }
            catch
            { }
        }

        richTextBox_receiveMsg.Text += data;

    }
```

EDIT based on your revised question:
To modify for sending blocks of a file you could added another Que

```
private ConcurrentQueue<string> dataOut = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
```

Then when you read the file, do whatever processing you need and put the final output in the queue and finish by sending the first block.

```
        public void openAndWrite()
        {
        /* load a .txt file */

        .
        .
        .

           while (offset < data.Length)
           {
            .
            .
            
            blockMsg += BitConverter.ToString(dataString).Replace("-", string.Empty);
            blockMsg += "*";

            dataOut.Enqueue(blockMsg);
           }
           
          SendBlock();
        }
```

Where SendBlock looks like this

```
    private void SendBlock()
    {
        if(dataOut.TryDequeue(out var data))
        {
            serialPort1.Write(data);
        }
    }
```

Then just modify the timer handler to send blocks as needed

```
    private void CheckQue(object state)
    {
        while (dataIn.TryDequeue(out var data))
        {
            ShowData(data);

            if (data.Contains("OK*"))
            {
                SendBlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I try to make something out of it but it's rather difficult. I guess I'm just lacking the basics here. So as far as I understand, serialPort1_DataReceived is already running on the Serial Port Thread so that on is listening all the time. Obivously the GUI is not updating when I want to halt in my loop to send the messages but I still can't wrap my head around how I get to the "OK*" message. Arduino is so much simpler. I added the full code in the op minus some functions that don't add to the problem.

Comment: The general idea is that you are always receiving from the serial port, when data comes in, the event(serialPort1_DataReceived) gets raised and in my suggestion, that event puts the data into a thread-safe container.  The timer looks at this container every second, and if any data is in it, will execute the show data and send code as needed.  This is happening on its own thread(the timer), so when modifying the form, you have to marshal the update on to the form's thread as shown in the ShowData method.

Comment: I'm assuming that your OK* message is coming from the Arduino, so it should show up in the ConcurrentQueue object at some point.  Thus why the If(data.Contains("OK*")) {..} was put there.

Comment: Ok after reading over your revised code above, I can see you're just trying to send a file to the Arduino and then wait for it to say OK*.   That does change how this is set up a bit.   In this case, I would probably start the process by breaking the file up into chunks that you want to send first.  Send the first chunk, and then as OK* comes back send the next chunk, and so on.   This would probably be best done in its own class that bubbles the event up to the form if you host it in a form.  Let me see if I can revise the answer a bit.

Comment: I updated this to show how you might queue up a file to send.  Its untested, just sudo code, but it does use a FIFO queue, so the blocks should come out in the order they were added, which is what I think your expecting. Good luck!